# Elasticsearch routing: only documents with one routing key per shard

Tags: elasticsearch, routes

We're currently optimzing the sharding setup of our Elasticsearch index to (surprise) decrease response times. Currently the amount of routing keys is equal to the amount of shards. We're looking for a setup, where **all documents in a shard are of one routing key only**.

This is how it is at the moment and how it should look like

**Current**

- shard:0 -> routes: bmx, cyclocrosser
- shard:1 -> routes: track-bike
- shard:2 -> routes:
- shard:3 -> routes: downhill

**Wanted**

- shard:0 -> routes: bmx
- shard:1 -> routes: track-bike
- shard:2 -> routes: cyclocrosser
- shard:3 -> routes: downhill

Is there any possibility to make sure, that one routing key will be **routed only to one shard**? Currently we're **facing empty shards**, which doesn't seems to be an appropriate solution.

We know that the routing is based on Murmur in version 5.50 (see: Murmur3HashFunction.java). Is there any option to influence this behavior and can someone offer deeper insights, how the routing works internally.

Comment: Built-in routing already achieves an equal distribution of documents over all shards. Your custom routing based on specific values will only achieve the same thing if you have an equal number of document for each routing value.

Comment: The document are more or less equally distributed over the routing key. This is the reason, why want to "assign" one routing key to one shard.

Comment: Are you sure that your set of routing keys will be eternally stable?, i.e. what happens if for some reason you need a new routing key at some point?

Comment: It is not necessary to have one routing key per shard in order to increase performance. The goal of a routing key is simply to direct the search at one specific shard (and not 5 or 6 different shards), but each shard doesn't have to have its own routing key.

Comment: yeah, I know that. The question is: is there an opportunity to have only document of one routing key in one shard? We're already having a quite advanced load metering with different routing setups and we wanted to know, if we can influence the routing in a stricter way.

Comment: Well, you can have a dictionary on the application-side which maps your routing keys to the shard number 0, 1, 2, 3 and then you can use the shard number as routing key, i.e. if `bmx` maps to 0 then search with `/_search?routing=0`

Comment: Try indexing four documents each with a different routing key 0, 1, 2, 3 and you'll see that you have one document per shard

Comment: This is the outcome: `shard 0  {0=101}
shard 1  {}
shard 2  {3=100}
shard 3  {1=100, 2=100, 4=99}`

Comment: Yeah, of course it is not that easy since the built-in hash function (Murmur3) doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the outcome: **It's not possible.**

**Why?** To work for the most use cases the routing is not directly based on the routing keys since the distribution of the documents might end up in a very unequal manner, if the distribution of routing key is like that (not for my case but in general it might be). The hashing of the routing key achieves this and even the disappearance of document having a certain routing will not end up in an empty shard.

You can create a workaround based on the knowledge of the used hashing function (Murmur) but this might break, if the Elasticsearch teams decides to changes the hashing function. And this happened already, so it's not save to rely on such a hidden feature.

The only way to achieve this is by creating a single index for each routing key as pointed out by Val.